# How to send requests as long as they are not successful in RxJava?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I use Retrofit + RxJava in my Android project. But my webservice has limits (1 reqest\second). So when I click "Load" button frequently then it returns JSON with error. Question: Which RxJava operator should I use to resend queries as long as they are not successful? Now I just have onError method called and that's it.

Comment: have you tried ``retry``? -http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/retry.html - I'm not sure but I think it doesn't really make the request again, but I thought you could give it a try since you already have a project setup

Comment: `throttleFirst` ? it will emit the first event, and will skip next events during the interval (here 1 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Use retryWhen operator, with 1 second of delay in your specific use case.

Here is a detailed explanation on same topic by Dan Lew, http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the json is not as you like, if it´s not you can throw a runtime exception, then using retryWhen, you can retry to get the json again. Then if all your tries fails, you can get the last error with operator onErrorResumeNext, and then return a default json if you want.

```
int count = 0;

@Test
public void observableOnErrorResumeNext() {
    Subscription subscription = Observable.just(new JsonObject())
                                          .doOnNext(json -> if(json == BAD_JSON){ throw RuntimeException() })
                                          .retryWhen(errors -> errors.doOnNext(o -> count++)
                                                                     .flatMap(t -> count > 3 ? Observable.error(t) : Observable.just(null).delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)),
                                                     Schedulers.newThread())
                                          .onErrorResumeNext(t -> {
                                              System.out.println("Error after all retries:" + t.getCause());
                                              return Observable.just("You can return here a default Json");
                                          })
                                          .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
    new TestSubscriber((Observer) subscription).awaitTerminalEvent(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

You can see more examples if you need here. https://github.com/politrons/reactive